# Does the parsing of the ABNF in RFC 5234 depend on string length?

Tags: rfc, abnf

For example, if I have ALPHA = <alphabetic character> and the rule [ALPHA], will the string "0" match on that rule? Will the string "aa" not match since the rule is equivalent to 0*1ALPHA and thus only at most 1 alpha character can be matched?

Comment: `[ALPHA]` is equivalent to `*1(ALPHA)` as per section 3.8 from that RFC. So, to answer your first question, i.e., `will the string "0" match on that rule?`, well no obviously, since `0` is not allowed (ALPHA only allows `A-Z` and `a-z`). To answer your second question, i.e., `will the string "aa" not match on the rule 0*1ALPHA`, the answer is that it won't indeed match as the rule allows for at most one character.

Comment: @JustinIurman Here's the confusion though, [ALPHA] will match on 0 or 1 ALPHAs, in the string "0" there are in fact no ALPHA's, so wouldn't it match since that satisfies that there are 0 ALPHAs? For the second case, I considered that, but then what about the rule [ALPHA] ALPHA? would that rule parse "aa"?

Comment: Typo, meant [ALPHA] ALPHA ALPHA on "aa". If [ALPHA] matches the first a and ALPHA matches the second, the second ALPHA matches nothing, but if [ALPHA] is interpreted to be 0 a characters then ALPHA ALPHA will match aa.

Comment: @jungon Try reading `[alpha]` as "The empty string, optionally followed by an `alpha`, followed by the end of the input.

Comment: @jungon `Here's the confusion though, [ALPHA] will match on 0 or 1 ALPHAs, in the string "0" there are in fact no ALPHA's, so wouldn't it match since that satisfies that there are 0 ALPHAs?` No, "0" wouldn't match. `[ALPHA]` means either 0 or 1 alpha character. The only things that would match is either the empty string, or only one alpha character. Since you're giving it "0", it wouldn't match on the alpha rule.

Comment: @JustinIurman so the [alpha] rule would just auto match to nothing and then the fact that there is a "0" left in the string means that the string doesn't match the rule?

Comment: @BjörnHöhrmann that makes the most sense to me, is there any document you could reference where the authors of the rfc said this specifically or implied it?

Comment: `so the [alpha] rule would just auto match to nothing and then the fact that there is a "0" left in the string means that the string doesn't match the rule?` I think you're overthinking too much. It's all about `does my rule matches the input or not`. So, if you apply `[ALPHA]` rule to "0", it won't match because the simple `[ALPHA]` rule matches only either the empty string or a single alpha character. A number (i.e., `0`) is not allowed by the rule. End of the story, plain and simple.

Comment: `that makes the most sense to me, is there any document you could reference where the authors of the rfc said this specifically or implied it?` It's probably not specified in the RFC simply because it does not need to be. Indeed, it's out of scope. This is pure regex behavior. What authors specified are the rules.